# Create a deeper category - like a sub-subcategory

Tags: javascript, php, html, content-management-system, forum

I'm havin this problem that my forum can only have a category and sub-category, but it is really neccessary to have a sub-subcategory

The CMS is called FusionCMS v5 and the system is a pain in the ass!
There are so many pages there, but i guess inc/forum.php and js/forum.js are the most important
If you could spend 1 min lookin for the problem I'd be very grateful, here's the link of the site "packed"

http://www.mediafire.com/download/wnsedk3zgprtcfg/admin.zip